# What do I add to my question?

Tags: discussion, support

Why has my question [What are the origins and evolutionary track of the Dominion game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53572/what-are-the-origins-and-evolutionary-track-of-the-dominion-game) been closed as needing details for clarity? What details do I need to add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first comment on your question is asking for clarification

> Wouldn't its origins and evolution be necessarily part of its history? What are you looking to find out that you have been unable to discover? What do you mean its origins and evolutionary track in particular?

People who read your question do not understand what exactly you are looking for, and how it would be different from what you have said you already found.

So the details you should add are explanations of what you mean by "origins" and "evolution", and specifically what was missing in the sources you found about the "history of Dominion".